# In JavaFX, how can I switch skins using CSS?

Tags: javafx-8, javafx-css

What is the correct place to define a `Skin` via CSS in JavaFX?  Say I have a very simple custom control...

```java
public class ActionLink extends Control {
    private final StringProperty text = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public final StringProperty textProperty() {return text;}
    public final String getText() {return text.get();}
    public final void setText(String text) {this.text.set(text);}
}
```

I know that I can specify the default skin in the control.  Assuming I have an `ActionLinkSkin`...

```java
@Override
protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
    return new ActionLinkSkin(this);
}
```

If I don't use `createDefaultSkin()`, I see a `SEVERE` warning indicating a skin can't be found:

```
The -fx-skin property has not been defined in CSS for ActionLink@59ebabd \
  and createDefaultSkin() returned null.
```

First off, I'm not certain where the control's CSS belongs.  Should I be using a stylesheet for the control, `action-link.css`, or should I be using a stylesheet for the skin, `action-link-skin.css`?  To me, it seems like the skin and CSS are going to be fairly interdependent, but using a stylesheet for the control seems to be more popular.

Second, and my main problem, I don't know where to define `-fx-skin` so it gets discovered correctly.

Now, assuming I have my CSS set up correctly, what if I want to include an alternate skin, `ActionLinkButtonSkin`?  Is there a way it can be set up so a parent component can select either skin via CSS?  For example:

```css
.action-link {
    -fx-skin: "ActionLinkSkin";
}
```

...or:

```css
.action-link {
    -fx-skin: "ActionLinkButtonSkin";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was having here is that I wasn't adding the `action-link` style to my control.  Here is a complete version of my simple `ActionLink` control:

```
public class ActionLink extends Control {
    static {
        // Stylesheets is a custom class that resides alongside my CSS files
        // and returns properly externalized locations in a convention based
        // manner.
        StyleManager.getInstance().addUserAgentStylesheet(
            Stylesheets.byConvention(ActionLink.class)
        );
    }

    private final StringProperty text = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public final StringProperty textProperty() {return text;}
    public final String getText() {return text.get();}
    public final void setText(String text) {this.text.set(text);}

    public ActionLink() {
        getStyleClass().setAll("action-link");
    }
}
```